# Google Slides Tables: setColumnWidth

Tags: google-apps-script, google-slides-api, google-slides

in Google Slides you can add a Table
and each Column in said table can be configured to a certain length
in my case i want each column to be
column1: 50pts
column2: 200pts
column3: 30pts
column4: 200pts
column5: 200pts

i cant seem to find a way to customize the width of a column in the docs
can someone help?
i have tried with

```js
var cellPadding = cell.getCellProperties().getPadding();
cellPadding.setLeft(targetColumnWidth / 2);
cellPadding.setRight(targetColumnWidth / 2);
cell.getCellProperties().setPadding(cellPadding);
```

and

```js
column.setWidth(targetColumnWidth);
```

neither of them works since `column.setWidth()` nor `cell.getCellProperties()` exist
Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Issue and workaround:

In the current stage, it seems that the width of the individual table row and column cannot be managed by the Google Slides service (SlidesApp). But, fortunately, when Slides API is used, it seems that your goal can be achieved. In this answer, I would like to propose a sample script using Slides API.

#### Sample script:

Please copy and paste the following script to the script editor of Google Slides, and save the script. Before you use this script, [please enable Google Slides API at Advanced Google services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enable_advanced_services).

```js
function myFunction() {
  const widths = [50, 200, 32, 200, 200]; // Widths for columns 1 to 5. These values are from your question.

  const s = SlidesApp.getActivePresentation();
  const slide = s.getSlides()[0]; // 1st page is used as a sample.
  const table = slide.getTables()[0]; // 1st table is used.

  const objectId = table.getObjectId();
  const requests = widths.map((e, i) => ({
    updateTableColumnProperties: {
      objectId, columnIndices: [i],
      tableColumnProperties: { columnWidth: { magnitude: e, unit: "PT" } },
      fields: "columnWidth"
    }
  }));
  Slides.Presentations.batchUpdate({ requests }, s.getId());
}
```

#### Testing:

When this script is used, the following result is obtained.

[image]

#### Note:

- In the current stage, it seems that the minimum width of a column using Slides API is 32 points. When 30 points are used, an error like `The table column width must be at least 406400 EMU (32 points).` occurs. So, I used 32 instead of 30 in your question. Please be careful about this.

#### References:

- [Method: presentations.batchUpdate](https://developers.google.com/slides/reference/rest/v1/presentations/batchUpdate)
- [UpdateTableColumnPropertiesRequest](https://developers.google.com/slides/api/reference/rest/v1/presentations/request#updatetablecolumnpropertiesrequest)

Comment: it didnt work :(
i gave up and accepted that my table is fated to look bad

ill still send the error thing just for other people who are having this problem

`GoogleJsonResponseException: API call to slides.presentations.batchUpdate failed with error: Invalid requests[0].updateTableColumnProperties: The object (SLIDES_API718451636_12) could not be found.`

for some reason it didnt think my slide id exists
but for sure i know it exists since i tested it

Comment: @Aspectx Thank you for replying. First, I deeply apologize for my poor English skill. From `OMG, THANK YOU SO MUCH`, I had thoought that your issue was resolved. Unfortunately, when I tested my script using a sample Slide, no error occurs. I deeply apologize for no error. But, I would like to support you. So, can you provide your sample Slide including the script for correctly replicating `The object (SLIDES_API718451636_12) could not be found.`? By this, I would like to confirm it. If you can cooperate to resolve your issue, I'm glad. Can you cooperate to do it?

Comment: @Aspectx By the way, about `The object (SLIDES_API718451636_12) could not be found.`, unfortunately, I cannot know your whole script from your question and reply. But, if a table is created in your actual script and modify the table using my script, please insert a script of `SlidesApp.getActivePresentation().saveAndClose();` just before the line of `const objectId = table.getObjectId();` in my script. By this, the created table can be used with Slides API. I'm worried that this might be the reason for your current issue. How about this? This is just my guess. I apologize for this.

Comment: huh that worked